# How to initialize data from a file when the site executes - django python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I want to build a dictionary translation site using django Python. I have a dictionary file available in dictionary.txt. Here is the format of the file:

```
Etc
Discusses: thảo luận
Deals with: giải quyết
Etc
```

I want to read this file when the site is executed. Because for processing I have a function that will read the data from dictionary.txt and save it to a dictionary data type in python. Can you help me?
This is my code, which reads data in .txt file:

```
def read_dictionary(fileName):
dict = {}
my_dict = {}
with open(fileName, 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split(':')
        key, values = items[0].replace('X','*'),items[1].strip().replace('\n','')
        dict[key] = values
for k, v in dict.items():
    my_dict.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
return my_dict
```

Comment: Take a look at Fixtures. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/. You will be better off storing your data as json or yaml rather than using your string parsing script.

Comment: ok, thanks.. I'll see it